# Сохранить состояние формы после отправки get запроса

Tags: python, django, django-template

Есть калькулятор доставки, после отправки get запроса страница перезагружается и рядом появляются результаты расчета.
Во views принимаю get параметры и отправляю обратно в шаблон.
Если в шаблоне вывести форму (RadioSelect) через {{ form.delivery_from_city }}, то состояние формы сохраняется:

```
<form method="GET">
    ...
    {{ form.delivery_from_city }} 
    ...
</form>
```

Если я меняю на HTML, состояние формы сбрасывается:

```
<div class="radio-conteyner">
    <div class="radio">
        <input id="id_delivery_to_city_0" class="custom-radio" type="radio" name="delivery_to_city" value="WD">
        <label for="id_delivery_to_city_0">До двери</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <input id="id_delivery_to_city_1" class="custom-radio" type="radio" name="delivery_to_city" value="DW">
        <label for="id_delivery_to_city_1">До склада</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как мне сохранить состояние формы для RadioSelect?
Внешний вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#checked)

```
... name="delivery_to_city" value="WD" 
{% if  form.delivery_from_city.value() == "WD" %}checked{% endif %} >
```

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо! Только value без скобок.

Comment: скопипастил наверное со старой версии джанго...)